# Dynamic columns into JSon

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, linq

Using .Net, We currently have a nested list model (list within a list) that represents a grid of data,so a list of columns within a list of rows
ie:-

```
public class TableViewModel 
{
   public List<List<TableColumn>> Grid { get; set; }
}


public class TableColumn
{
    public TableColumn() { }

    public TableColumn(string columnHeader, string columnValue, int columnWidth, EnumColumnType columnType, string columnName)
    {
        this.ColumnHeader = columnHeader;
        this.ColumnValue = columnValue;
        this.ColumnWidth = columnWidth;
        this.ColumnType = columnType;
        this.ColumnName = columnName;
    }

    public string               ColumnHeader    { get; set; }
    public string               ColumnName      { get; set; }
    public string               ColumnValue     { get; set; }
    public int                  ColumnWidth     { get; set; }
    public EnumColumnType       ColumnType      { get; set; }  
}
```

This works great when returning dynamic columns from SQL, how ever, 
what we are really struggling to achieve, is to now transpose this into correct JSON using

```
List<List<TableColumn>> lst= getlist();
return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

it needs to be represented as :-

```
 [
    {name: 'Moroni', age: 50},
    {name: 'Tiancum', age: 43},
    {name: 'Jacob', age: 27},
    {name: 'Nephi', age: 29},
    {name: 'Enos', age: 34}];
 ]
```

where name and age are column headers (ColumnHeader from the model) and the correspondence is the value (ColumnValue from the model)

What would the Linq be to create this to produce the correct JSON which is returned?

Much appreciated, as we've really been struggling with this..

UPDATE :- Sample data for below message

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<List<test>> m = new List<List<test>>();
    List<test> lt = new List<test>();

   lt.Add(new test { ColumnName = "cn1", ColumnValue = "cv1" });
   lt.Add(new test { ColumnName = "cn2", ColumnValue = "cv2" });
   lt.Add(new test { ColumnName = "cn3", ColumnValue = "cv3" });
   m.Add(lt);

  lt = new List<test>();

   lt.Add(new test { ColumnName = "cn12", ColumnValue = "cv12" });
   lt.Add(new test { ColumnName = "cn22", ColumnValue = "cv22" });
   lt.Add(new test { ColumnName = "cn32", ColumnValue = "cv32" });
   m.Add(lt);


}

public class test
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what json framework are you using, e.g. json.net, javascriptserializer, etc?

Comment: the one built into MVC system.web.mvc.JsonResult

Comment: We are trying to return the correct format Json for use with angular Grid but struggling to use Linq to manipulate the nested list to create this Json

Comment: I think you need to convert your `List<List<TableColumn>>`  to something like `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` before you pass it to the Json method.  Have you tried that?

Comment: thank you for your reply,  but not quite sure how creating a list of dictionaries would be any different?

Comment: @Simon try and see. It is correct.

Comment: hi, i'll give that a go, is there a way to use LINQ to populate the List<Dictionary<string, string>> from our current List<List<TableColumn>>

Comment: @Simon `is there a way ....` Yes but to answer that, I should create a case with some sample data. If you had posted it, It would be a one minute answer, but I am not willing to do this tedious work. For  future questions see [this](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: It might be possible using Linq, but I think it would be just as easy to do it 'manually' -- loop through your source list and convert it item by item.  Shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @L.B apologies, I've now added sample data to the question also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = m.Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.ColumnName, y => y.ColumnValue))
           .ToList();
```

Just serialize/return obj.

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "cn1": "cv1",
    "cn2": "cv2",
    "cn3": "cv3"
  },
  {
    "cn12": "cv12",
    "cn22": "cv22",
    "cn32": "cv32"
  }
]
```